# Show error after install phpmyadmin on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I install phpmyadmin on ubuntu 16.04.

PHP version is 7.2

After login to phpmyadmin show this error:

```
Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#532
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements 
Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/display_import.lib.php#368: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Import',
array,
)
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#453:     PMA_getHtmlForImportOptionsFormat(array)
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#684: PMA_getHtmlForImport(
string '5ac5e28f893ca',
string 'database',
string 'oro',
string '',
integer 2097152,
array,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
)
./db_import.php#40: PMA_getImportDisplay(
string 'database',
string 'oro',
string '',
integer 2097152,
)
```

How to issue this problem?

Comment: What version of phpmyadmin do you use? Try updating to the latest stable version. Previous version got problems with PHP 7.2

Comment: @wayneOS Hi, How to install stable version?

Comment: @wayneOS How to check phpmyadmin version?

Comment: good question if you cant see the home-site after login. i will come back to you shortly. have to check that for myself.

Comment: ok, under `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` is a file `RELEASE-DATE-*` with your current version instead of the  `*`

Comment: I can't file `RELEASE-DATE-*` :-(

Comment: maybe try `sudo find / -name RELEASE-DATE-*`

Comment: Did you install phpMyAdmin by using the package manager (apt/syntaptic/aptitude) or by downloading it yourself from the phpMyAdmin site (as a compressed file you uncompressed to your web root)? `dpkg -l phpmyadmin` should tell you whether the package is installed. Download instructions are at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html (I'd look for the quick install section), but you should first remove your existing one so as to not conflict the two versions.

Answer (score 1):

Edit => `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php`

Find => `if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {`

Change =>  `if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {`

Restart Apache => `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score -3):

If you want to install php 7.2 please refer.

```
apt-get install -y python-software-properties
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update -y

apt-get install php7.2  -y 

apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-fpm php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-mysql php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip  php7.2-gd php7.2-
curl php7.2-xml php7.2-readline
```